# What flashes are compatible with the Canon A-1?

Tags: canon, equipment-recommendation, flash, compatibility, vintage

What vintage/modern flashes are compatible with the Canon A-1? I'm going away for vacation and I need something other than a tripod for low-light situations.

Comment: I used to use a Canon Speedlite 533G with my A-1

Comment: @dav1dsm1th, better than the 199a? That's what I'm presently looking at, however, a better option is always appreciated.

Comment: Couldn't say, as I only had experience with the 533G - but I was never disappointed with it.

Comment: Don't know if I want to walk around with a flash that doubles the size of my camera, I'm looking more at shoe-mount flashes, either hot or cold.

Comment: Just looked at some info on the 199a and it appears to be just as integrated to the A-1 as the 533G, so I think you can be confident it's a good piece of kit.  http://www.mir.com.my/rb/photography/companies/canon/fdresources/SLRs/a1/html/index6.htm

Comment: In case you haven't seen it: a similar question spawned [a thread at photo.net](http://photo.net/canon-fd-camera-forum/00YQbw).

Answer (score 1):

Everything with a standard hotshoe should work. Flashes are pretty universal, even today, you can buy a Nikon flash and use it on a Canon camera all day long.

The flash should support a manual mode though. The A-1 doesn't have TTL (what is used to sent data about exposure to the flash, telling it how powerful the flash should be).

Comment: *In manual mode